# AS3 leaving and returning to the code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to create a flash application which will demonstrate at each step of the algorithm, how variables are changed (like a debug). The algorithm is max-flow. I want to have 3 buttons: play, pause and next-step.

In general I need somehow to exit from the event which calls the function, check if any buttons were clicked and get to the place in the code were i left.

```
function flux():void
{
    var x,i,d,q:int;
    do
    {
        x = activ();
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (vert[i].stare == 0 && a[x][i] > 0 && e[x][i] < a[x][i])
            {
                d = a[x][i] - e[x][i];
                if (d<vert[x].flux)
                {
                    vert[i].flux = d;
                }
                else
                {
                    vert[i].flux = vert[x].flux;
                }

                vert[i].stare = 1;
                vert[i].sursa = x;
            }
        }
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (vert[i].stare == 0 && e[i][x] > 0)
            {

                d = e[i][x];
                if (d<vert[x].flux)
                {

                    vert[i].flux = d;
                }
                else
                {

                    vert[i].flux = vert[x].flux;
                }
                vert[i].stare = 1;
                vert[i].sursa =  -  x;

            }
        }
        vert[x].stare = 2;
    } while (vert[f].stare!=1 && activ()!=0);

    delt = 0;
    if (vert[f].stare == 1)
    {
        x = f;
        delt = vert[f].flux;
        do
        {
            q = abs(vert[x].sursa);
            if (vert[x].sursa < 0)
            {
                e[q][x] -=  delt;
            }
            if (vert[x].sursa > 0)
            {
                e[q][x] +=  delt;
            }
            x = q;
        } while (x!=st);
    }
}
```

At first i thought i would use labels, coming from c++, but in AS3 they are used only for loops.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but you can System.pause() the running application as long as it's in debug mode running in a debug player. You could just pause and resume your code when you like and trace/display the textfield with the data you want just before that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a queue system for instructions, and pause while accessing them, one by one. These instructions should also be a queue instance of subinstructions, too. These instructions would be functions or perhaps objects with methods.

Check out **PureMVC**'s command system, it may be what you are looking for.